# Finding extreme value of function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Given $f(x,y,z) = 3 \log( x^2+y^2+z^2) -2x^2-2y^3-2z^3$, $(x,y,z) \neq (0,0,0)$, find the extremum value of $f$.

$f_x = \frac{6x}{x^2+y^2+z^2} - 4x$

$f_y = \frac{6y}{x^2+y^2+z^2} - 6y^2$

$f_z = \frac{6z}{x^2+y^2+z^2} - 6z^2$

How do I proceed ?

Comment: What are you trying to find?

Comment: point (x,y,z) ….

Comment: As @AlexanderGeldhof stated, there might be saddle points so make sure to be careful and check all the critical points. You can also make use of the second derivatives test.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: Equating $f_x,f_y,f_z$ to $0$ gives (remember $x^2+y^2+z^2\neq 0$)
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x(3-2(x^2+y^2+z^2)) &= 0\\
y(1-y(x^2+y^2+z^2)) &= 0\\
z(1-z(x^2+y^2+z^2)) &= 0
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
Now solve by considering cases.

Comment: From equation 1 we get $r^2 = 3/2 , r^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$. from 2,3 I get$ y=z=2/3$. not sure how to proceed

Comment: Why do you think you can cancel $x,y,z$?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: There are a total of 8 cases to consider here.  Some of them are obviously not compatible with each other, and some of them are not compatible with $(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)$.  You can't just consider one of the 8 cases.

Comment: 8 cases ..how so ?

Comment: Because individually, $x$, $y$ and $z$ could be zero, which is the point of my first comment "(w)hy do you think you can cancel $x,y,z$?".

Comment: I don't see to find 8 cases you are talking about, can you elaborate ?